# Using pyshp to read a file-like object from a zipped archive

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp

Presume I have an archive, foo.zip. It contains the parts of a shapefile: foo.shp, foo.dbf, foo.shx, foo.prj, and foo.cpg. I want to work with this shapefile in python, using pyshp, AKA the shapefile library.

Right now, I can extract the archive to disk, then read in the shapefile:

```
r = shapefile.Reader('foo')
```

I have quite a few such archives, though, and it would be nice to be able to read in these files without having to first extract each archive. According to [pyshp's documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp), you can read in a file-like object with syntax like this:

```
myshp = open('foo.shp', 'rb')
mydbf = open('foo.dbf', 'rb')
r = shapefile.Reader(shp=myshp, dbf=mydbf)
```

And I quote: "This feature is very powerful and allows you to load shapefiles from a url, **from a zip file**, serialized object, or in some cases a database."

Thus I have tried creating a file-like object from my archive. First, creating the archive:

```
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('foo.zip')
```

Works fine. But if I then try

```
r = shapefile.Reader(archive.open('foo.shp')
```

I get the error, "shapefile.ShapefileException: Shapefile Reader requires a shapefile or file-like object."

That's legit; I should be passing it a file-like object. So I tried modifying the documentation's canonical example:

```
myshp = archive.open('foo.shp', 'r')
mydbf = archive.open('foo.dbf', 'r')
r = shapefile.Reader(shp=myshp, dbf=mydbf)
```

But this produces the error, "io.UnsupportedOperation: seek".

For what it is worth, I cannot use 'rb' as an option with archive.open(). If I do, I am told, "RuntimeError: open() requires mode 'r', 'U', or 'rU'". Also, using "archive.read()" instead of "archive.open()" just produces the "...requires a shapefile or file-like object" error.

I am stumped. As far as I can tell, I have created *archive* correctly, I have correctly used archive.open() to grab files as file-like objects, and I have used the correct syntax to have pyshp read from a file-like object. And yet, these errors. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Has anyone had success passing file-like objects from zip archives to pyshp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been using `StringIO` for reading zipped shapefiles with `pyshp` and it worked fine.

```
#shapefile.__version__ '1.2.3'


from __future__ import print_function
import zipfile
import StringIO
import shapefile

zipshape = zipfile.ZipFile(open(r'C:\GIS\Temp\RoadsShapefileFolder.zip', 'rb'))
print(zipshape.namelist())
dbfname, _, shpname, _, shxname = zipshape.namelist()
r = shapefile.Reader(shp=StringIO.StringIO(zipshape.read(shpname)),
                     shx=StringIO.StringIO(zipshape.read(shxname)),
                     dbf=StringIO.StringIO(zipshape.read(dbfname)))

print(r.bbox)
print(r.numRecords)
```

Output:

```
['Roads.dbf', 'Roads.prj', 'Roads.shp', 'Roads.shp.xml', 'Roads.shx']
[279629.7664999999, 6137207.9419, 916929.7043000003, 7595571.024099998]
365
```

Make sure you access the right files within the zip as they are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Thank you--that seemed to do the trick. On [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371860/python-open-file-from-zip-without-temporary-extracting-it), someone noted that "read returns a string with the file's contents; open returns a file-like object." It seems telling that reading and then passing through StringIO works, while the straight open does not seem to. Odd--but I'll take this solution!

Comment: In python 3 you should use `BytesIO` from the `io` package.

Comment: Can someone show me an example using Bytes io? I am still getting ```shapefile.ShapefileException: Shapefile Reader requires a shapefile or file-like object.```

from 

```
as_like = io.BytesIO(as_zips.read(shapes[0])
)```

Answer (score 4):

These days, opening a shapefile contained in a zip works just fine:

```
def ecoregion():
    """
    >>> eco = ecoregions()
    >>> eco.fields
    [('DeletionFlag', 'C', 1, 0),
     ['OBJECTID', 'N', 32, 10],
     ['ECO_NAME', 'C', 150, 0],
     ['BIOME_NUM', 'N', 32, 10],
     ['BIOME_NAME', 'C', 254, 0],
     ['REALM', 'C', 254, 0],
     ['ECO_BIOME_', 'C', 254, 0],
     ['NNH', 'N', 11, 0],
     ['ECO_ID', 'N', 11, 0],
     ['SHAPE_LENG', 'N', 32, 10],
     ['SHAPE_AREA', 'N', 32, 10],
     ['NNH_NAME', 'C', 64, 0],
     ['COLOR', 'C', 7, 0],
     ['COLOR_BIO', 'C', 7, 0],
     ['COLOR_NNH', 'C', 7, 0],
     ['LICENSE', 'C', 64, 0]]
    """
    zipshape = zipfile.ZipFile(
        (Path(__file__).parent.parent / "ecoregions/Ecoregions2017.zip").open("rb"))
    shape = shapefile.Reader(
        shp=zipshape.open("Ecoregions2017.shp"),
        shx=zipshape.open("Ecoregions2017.shx"),
        dbf=zipshape.open("Ecoregions2017.dbf"),
    )
    return shape
```